# Can't aim command line at one of multiple running instances since upgrading to Firefox 9

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line

Upgrading from Firefox 8 to Firefox 9 on Linux (Ubuntu Lucid) broke a feature I use often: Running multiple instances, then aiming command line Firefox at a specific running instance.

Any ideas on how to fix or work around this?

I run two Firefox instances with separate profiles:

```
firefox -no-remote -P personal
firefox -no-remote -P work
```

(The `-no-remote` is necessary for the second to start a new instance, and not just a new window in the first instance.)

I then use this to open a URL in one of the running instances:

```
firefox -P personal http://asdf.com
```

This worked through Firefox 8, but in 9, I instead get the error message

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

Same with these variations:

```
firefox -P personal -new-tab http://asdf.com
firefox -P personal -new-window http://asdf.com
firefox -P personal -remote "openURL(http://asdf.com,new-tab)"
```

It looks like the initial `-no-remote` flag changed in Firefox 9 to also prevent connections from future command lines. If I start an instance without `-no-remote`, I can successfully open a tab in it from the command line, but I can't start a second instance that way, so that doesn't help much.

Comment: this may be the same problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=703021

Comment: looks like this may have been caused by a "bug fix" in ff9 that made -no-remote also not listen for remote commands, in addition to not reusing a running instance. i'm talking with the mozilla people about it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650078

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/528173/run-different-firefox-profiles-concurrently it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jed davis [posted a patch](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716110#c5) that fixes this by splitting a -new-instance flag out of -no-remote. hopefully it will land in an upcoming firefox release.

Comment: Seems to have landed.

Comment: hi @ryan, can you please write me some steps to follow to open my second profile called "Dev". Right now i am doing 1) open my default profile 2) launch dev profile with `firefox.exe -P Dev -no-remote` this works, but if i then do 3) `firefox.exe -P Dev -new-tab "about:blank" it wont open the new tab in it, it opens in the default :(

Comment: Oh im using Windows

Comment: @Noitidart good question! i'm not sure how to target different windows via the command line, especially on windows. sorry.

Comment: Thanks @ryan for the reply, I'll dig around in the buzilla topics linked, thanks for your effort on this. :) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716110#c33