# Launch 10 Firefox profile windows simultaneously?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-profile

I would like to open 10 Firefox profile windows simultaneously on Ubuntu desktop. I know how to do this on Windows but the application doesn't exist on Ubuntu. I have tried Profile Manager in Terminal but this is limited to 2 simultaneous profiles.

Comment: Related: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/528192/109256) explains how to use several profiles `--no-remote` option on Windows. Similarly applicable on Linux. Sure, I sometimes use three profiles simultanenously on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use from console the command line option:

```
firefox --profilemanager &
```

This will open firefox in the Profile Manager mode and can be done multiple times, thanks to the ampersand (&) at the end. This will start Firefox and return to the prompt again (though some debug info may show, just hit enter again, arrow key up, and enter key again :)